# Вызов sys_write при помощи syscall не выводит сообщение в терминал

Tags: linux, ассемблер, gnu-assembler

Код:

```
.data
 message: .ascii "ASSEMBLY OUTPUT"

  .text
.globl _start

 _start:
movq $1, %rdi
movq $1, %rax
movq $15, %rdx
movq $message, %rsi
syscall
movq $60, %rax
movq $0, %rdi
syscall
```

В RAX после первого syscall результат -14. Программа компилируется и не выдаёт ошибок при запуске, но не выводит ничего в терминал. Что не так с вызовом?

Comment: УМВР. как именно собирал?

Comment: Добавил в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы строку было видно, нужно добавить служебные символы переноса и изменить длину строки.

```
.data
message: .ascii "\nASSEMBLY OUTPUT\n\n"

 .text
.globl _start

_start:
movq $1, %rdi
movq $1, %rax
movq $18, %rdx
movq $message, %rsi
syscall
movq $60, %rax
movq $0, %rdi
syscall
```

Команды сборки через binutils и запуска в терминале Linux:

> as -g -o main.o main.s
>
> ld -o main main.o
>
> ./main

**UPDATE**

Можно сделать без перевода строки, как подсказали в комментариях. Код с изменениями:

```
 .data
message: .ascii "ASSEMBLY OUTPUT MESSAGE"
.equ one, 1
len = . - message

 .text
.globl _start

_start:
movq $one, %rdi
movq $one, %rax
movq $len, %rdx
movq $message, %rsi
syscall #sys_write
movq $74, %rax #rdi == 1
syscall #fsync
movq $60, %rax
xor %rdi, %rdi
syscall #exit
```

Сборка:

> as -g -mintel64 -mtune=corei7 -o main.o main.s
>
> ld -Ofast -o main main.o

Версия as: GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30.
Версия ld: GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30.
Версия gdb: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git.

Дизассемблированный код в отладчике:

```
   0x00000000004000b0 <+0>: mov    $0x1,%rdi
   0x00000000004000b7 <+7>: mov    $0x1,%rax
   0x00000000004000be <+14>:    mov    $0x17,%rdx
   0x00000000004000c5 <+21>:    mov    $0x6000e3,%rsi
   0x00000000004000cc <+28>:    syscall 
   0x00000000004000ce <+30>:    mov    $0x4a,%rax
   0x00000000004000d5 <+37>:    syscall 
   0x00000000004000d7 <+39>:    mov    $0x3c,%rax
   0x00000000004000de <+46>:    xor    %rdi,%rdi
   0x00000000004000e1 <+49>:    syscall
```

О порядке записи значений в регистры для передачи параметров в системные вызовы написано здесь: https://www.raywenderlich.com/615-assembly-register-calling-convention-tutorial
Сигнатура syscall дана здесь: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux
Эффект fsync дан здесь: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fdatasync.2.html
Эффект sys_write: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html
Номера использованных вызовов syscall даны тут: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl
Эффект exit можно посмотреть здесь: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html

Описание опций вызовов as и ld доступно в справке с параметром -help через терминал.

Comment: вообще говоря, это ни как не должно повлиять...

Comment: А вдруг однажды появится задача вывести строку именно без переносов? Так что как-то сомнительный ответ. Я в ассемблерах не разбираюсь, но предположил бы, что где-нибудь какой-нибудь flush забыт

Comment: Спасибо. Я не знал про flush. Добавил изменение.